# the order of Goroutines runs

Tags: go

I am learning Golang right now, and came across some interesting tutorial online. for example this one: https://golangbot.com/channels/

in this part about goroutines, there is one example case as following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func producer(chnl chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("debugging send...", i)
        chnl <- i
    }
    close(chnl)
}
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go producer(ch)
    for {
        v, ok := <-ch
        if ok == false {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("Received ", v, ok)
    }
}
```

the line `fmt.Println("debugging send...", i)` is added by me for debugging purpose. and the output is:

```
debugging send... 0
debugging send... 1
Received  0 true
Received  1 true
debugging send... 2
debugging send... 3
Received  2 true
Received  3 true
debugging send... 4
debugging send... 5
Received  4 true
Received  5 true
debugging send... 6
debugging send... 7
Received  6 true
Received  7 true
debugging send... 8
debugging send... 9
Received  8 true
Received  9 true
```

The output order seems interesting for me, but can't fully understand what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

The only places where there's synchronization is the channel operations. There need not be correlation between the order of operations in the goroutines outside of those statements.

Running your program multiple times, I got the output you have most of the time but sometimes I saw something like this as well:

```
debugging send... 0
debugging send... 1
Received  0 true
Received  1 true
debugging send... 2
debugging send... 3
Received  2 true
Received  3 true
debugging send... 4
debugging send... 5
Received  4 true
Received  5 true
debugging send... 6
debugging send... 7
Received  6 true
debugging send... 8
Received  7 true
Received  8 true
debugging send... 9
Received  9 true
```

Try running this Bash shell script to run the program multiple times and compare its output:

```
#!/bin/bash

# c.go has your Go program
go run c.go > first.txt
cat first.txt

echo "======"
while :; do
    go run c.go > run.txt
    if ! diff -q run.txt first.txt; then
        break
    fi
done

cat run.txt
```

Edit: You may find https://golang.org/ref/mem interesting to read about synchronization in Go.

Answer (score 1):

it's the way in which go routines communicate. You can use a channel for such synchronisation or some memory lock mechanism for achieving the same.

If you're interested in reading more checkout these links

1. http://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part1.html
2. https://rakyll.org/scheduler/
3. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yIAYmbvL3JxOKOjuCyon7JhW4cSv1wy5hC0ApeGMV9s/pub